# read the first line of a text file with JQ

Tags: linux, bash, jq

Trying to see how I can read the first line of a text file using `jq`

I have a text file with a bunch of ids (newfile.txt )

```
5584157003
5584158003
5584159003
5584160003
```

id like to be able to just read the first line with jq.

I tried doing this

```
cat newfile.txt | jq '.[0]'
```

But getting an error of

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:482): Cannot index number with number
```

I'd like to be able to read line by line so that I can eventually run a look with that ID and be able to do stuff with it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-R` argument (aka `--raw-input`) to tell `jq` that it's receiving input as strings rather than JSON, and use `input` to read only a single item at a time. Thus:

```
jq -Rn input <yourfile
```

...will output:

```json
"5584157003"
```

---

If you want to convert it to a number, that's what `tonumber` is for:

```
jq -Rn 'input | tonumber' <yourfile
```

...which will output:

```json
5584157003
```

Comment: what about reading line 2 only, is there arguments to pass here to do that with jq?

Comment: `[input, input]` will give you a list with only two lines. You can also throw away the first line and read only the second, if you like. I might write it as `jq -Rn 'input as $ignore | input'` in that particular case just for clarity; to loop and ignore a specific number of items, by contrast, I'd probably use a reducer.

Comment: is there a way to specifically retrieve a line number?  for example line 3? `5584159003`

Comment: Are you okay with reading the whole file, or do you want to only read the number of lines needed?

Comment: what I am ultimately trying to do is fetch each line number from this file one by one and make an api call using bash.

Comment: `jq -Rs 'split("\n") | .[2]'` is maybe the _easiest_ way to get only line 3, but it's not particularly efficient.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't recommend doing it one jq call per line at all.

Comment: ...instead, I'd using a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to process the input file line by line.

Comment: Even if you unavoidably need to call jq, it's better to call jq _only once_ and have that single instance of jq generate a stream of lines that you can then use a `while read` loop to iterate over.

Comment: got it, yea, bash makes more sense in this case. but good to know on this.

Comment: or even using sed, would be better as well.   `sed '2!d' newfile.txt`

Comment: @chewie - I think you'll find `sed -n '2p;q` to be faster, at least usually.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to specifically retrieve a line number? for example line 3?

If no transformation need be done, then using `sed` would probably be the simplest, efficient approach; if a simple transformation is required, then besides `sed`, `awk` might be worth considering, but jq might also be worth considering under certain circumstances.

In particular, if efficiency is a consideration, then it would make sense to use jq's `nth` filter, along the lines of:

```
jq --argjson n 3 -nR 'nth($n - 1; inputs)' newfile.txt
```

This approach will avoid reading lines beyond the specified one.

(`nth` counts from 0.)

You might also want to use jq's -r option.

Answer (score 0):

> what I am ultimately trying to do is fetch each line number from this file one by one and make an api call using bash.

For a straightforward task like that, you could simply use bash's read, along the lines of

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do ... done < newfile.txt
```

If any kind of transformation of the input lines needs to be done, however, jq might be appropriate, e.g. if the lines must be URL-encoded.  This could be done using `inputs` in conjunction with jq's -n and -R command-line options, along the lines of:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do 
... 
done < <(jq -Rrn 'inputs|@uri' newfile.txt)
```